# How to use <h:selectOneRadio> on more than one datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, radio-button

I'm trying to achieve the well known feature of being able to select a datatable's row by using a radio button.

I have followed this blog:

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SelectRowByRadioButton

It works perfectly if there is one datatable on the form, but when I add another one (even if it's placed on other form), and try to select a row there, the radio button gets selected then instantly unselected. The data is correctly set on the backing bean though.

Any ideas about how to extend the results of the above blog on more than one datatable?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script will group all radio buttons with the same component ID in the same form. So to fix your particular problem, put the other data table in a different form or give the other `<h:selectOneRadio>` a different ID.

Comment: The problem was related to an incorrect usage of ajax re-rendering. Thanks for your article, it has been very useful.